# c# Insert multiple records based on time span using entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity, timespan

I am writing a task scheduling app and have most of it done. I want to update the app now to handle tasks that are 8 Hours or more.

What I am trying to do is. If I add a task for 20 hours on Tuesday from 9:00 AM, I want my method to create multiple entities/records and insert in the DB (8 Hrs, 8 Hrs and 4 Hrs in this case, with all details the same except the start and end time.)

```
public PartialViewResult Add(FormCollection collection)
{      
    try
    {
        using(var _dbContext = new myContext())
        {
             string _UserName = collection["UserName"].ToString();
             string _TaskName = collection["TaskName"].ToString();

             DateTime _dtTaskStart = new DateTime();
             DateTime.TryParse(collection["dtTaskStart"], out _dtTaskStart);

             DateTime _dtTaskEnd = new DateTime();
             DateTime.TryParse(collection["dtTaskEnd"], out _dtTaskEnd);

             List<Task> _Tasks = new List<Task>();

             //total task hrs
             Double _TotalTaskHrs = (_dtTaskEnd - _dtTaskStart).TotalHours;

             if(_TotalTaskHrs  > 8)
             {
                 /*1. Here want to get an array that gives me the split hours 8,8,4*/
                 /*2. Once I get 8,8,4 (This can be stored as an array) from which I can tell I have to create 3 entries */
                 /*3. Copy values from form collection to all three entries*/
                 /*4. Add all tasks to the list*/

                 _dbContext.Tasks.Attach(/*Created entity*/);
                 _dbContext.SaveChanges();    
             }
         }
     }
     catch(Exception Ex)
     {

     }       
 }
```

I am not sure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: Start by creating a model, binding to your model using `HtmlHelper` megtods and pass back the model to `public PartialViewResult Add(YourModel mdoel) {   }` (do not use `FormCollection`). You could use `_TotalTaskHrs / 8` to get the number of '8 hour' increments, and `_TotalTaskHrs  % 8` operator to get the remainder

Comment: But you should not be duplicating all that data in the database table. Normalize your data and create a table for the Task details and a 1-many table for the dates associated with a task

Comment: Thanks, If I normalize the data, I will have to create multiple tables. As there are chances that the tasks that are split can be assigned to different users any have different notes on them. 

Also, thought there would be an easier way or some kind of math op to get 8,8,4 but  / and % works too.

Will update it to pass model :) 

Thanks